# What is a realistic psychological response to magic?

Tags: magic, psychology, merfolk

So I think about this a lot based on seeing things like clichés or unrealistic reactions - how would someone actually react to magic?

In some media, the character is in unbelievable denial - you've obviously seen magic, why are you acting like it still doesn't exist?

Other times people are waaay too accepting, to the point that it feels really weird how they don't bat an eye at seeing wizards and dragons.

In my story specifically, my character is kidnapped by merfolk, and then turned into one (very simple merfolk, just a human with a blue fish tail replacing the legs). I should note in my world, magic and merfolk are widely known to exist, but such a transformation is the subject of dark stories.

Psychologically speaking, how should my character react to this? Obviously everyone is different, and thus will have different reactions, but should I expect things like my character having lasting psychological damage from this?

Specifically I'm looking for some real world analogues, in how people react to such dramatic revelations. General thoughts on reaction to magic, not just my specific case, are also welcome.

Edit, further info on my character:

My character, Irian was raised on a farm in an industrial era world before moving to a port city, where he is now 18. Irian's chief personality trait is stubborness, and as the humans and merpeople are locked in a small scale war, he has a less than favorable view of them. Irian worked as a scale farmer - captured merfolk have their colorful scales periodically harvested to make jewelry.

Thus, being captured by escaping merfolk, and becoming one himself, causes great strain to him, especially because he is then basically enslaved to forage food for the merfolk.

I do however, want some air of realism with how he should react, because right now, it feels like he adjusts to it far too well. I'm wondering if I should look at stuff like the five stages of grief.

Comment: I think it would be useful to describe the age of your character, what level of mental flexibility they have in terms of personality, and what emotional support they have after the transformation?  I mean the nicest analogy I can think of is the situation of war refugees, driven from the surroundings and people they once knew into a unfamiliar and often hostile new circumstances; even more unsavory analogies come to mind.  A high level of grief and mental trauma is to be expected.

Comment: Too broad. (a) There is pain in the transformation, or some kind of altaration in the cognitive functions?.

Comment: @grumpyyoungman Added some info on my character.

Comment: @edrel von Mises I don't think it's too broad. I simply want info on how someone might realistically react to supernatural events.

Comment: This is still very broad. We react differently to supernatural events that happen to others from those that happen to us. There is also a broad reaction to events that happen to us. Compare your event with someone who lost their legs in an accident as opposed to someone who was abused by their parents to lose their legs. The two will have very different reactions because of how everyone else reacts and what support they receive. You might also read up on how people responded to being captured, sold as slaves, and transported to the Americas to work in plantations.

Comment: VTC:NAW. The [help/on-topic] states, "If … you aren’t sure what a character (be it an individual or organization) should do, that is out of scope for the site." It doesn't matter how narrow the scope, asking about character actions and decisions is off-topic. If you knew *everything* about the *one circumstance* where *one* character was introduced to magic, it *might* be possible to offer an objective answer - but it would require knowing *everything* about the character, which isn't possible. See also: [narrative necessity](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7281/40609).

Comment: @Join JBH Okay okay I get it can I please delete my message so people will stop calling me dumb for making a mistake?

Comment: @WasatchWind Did someone call you dumb? All I see are people pointing out the rules of the Stack. Unfortunately, the moment someone answers a question, the question can no longer be deleted but by community vote. If you think it's difficult reminding users to ask well-asked questions, it's a chore reminding users to [only answer well-asked questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact it's just annoying when I have it made clear that my question was bad, only to have people feel the need to tell it to me over and over again. I only need to be told once.

Comment: I think if you reframe your questions and ask for typical reactions expected in this situation from a person with specific psychological traits it will be possible to bring it to meta and argue that it should be reopened. It will not be easy, but with some more edits it might happen. I am not sure if you are willing to try it.  I personally think that this is a potentially good worldbuilding question.

Comment: @Otkin really I just cave to whatever the people cry out against me. When I voiced my frustration in the past I was made fun of or considered an obnoxious a-hole. I just don't like that people don't say "maybe reword your question" - they just downvote your question, say it's dumb, and then tons more people do the same. The only reason I use the site is because of people who are actually nice and helpful in the midst of all the rude pragmatics who are obsessed with everything being perfectly worded.

Comment: I understand your frustration and I do agree that the rhetoric used by some users is not the best way to make their point or to help you to improve your question. I usually flag those comments and they frequently get deleted. || Going back to my proposal to bring this to meta, are you willing to do it? I do not have much time, but I can spare up to 2 hours a day to try and help you with this question. (My reason is that I believe that questions about psychology are on-topic and there should be more of them on the WB.SE)

Comment: @Otkin It's okay. I've rewritten the scene and I'm happy with it. I'm mostly just frustrated that everyone on this site seems mortified of people talking about something as off topic as WRITING a story. If anyone seems like they are even slightly asking for advice on how to write, they think it is off topic or out of focus. I ask the same question on writing se, and they all tell me to go to worldbuilding se.  It's very annoying, and people on writing forums don't have the expertise they need.

Answer (score 1):

## The magic won't be too shocking.

Plastic surgery [has a long history](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/history-of-plastic-surgery) and people were aware of the idea that you could sew animal parts to a person, or that diseases could change you to look more like some sort of animal. It would be weird, but not that far out of what people expect.

## Radically changing his body will be traumatizing.

Imagine how people react when their limbs are removed. Phantom limb syndrome, body dysmorphia, depression and suicidability. People have long term consequences when they lose body parts that take a while to get over.

Answer (score 0):

This question isnt about the magic. The magic is well known in this world. This question is about mutilation and loss of limb.

In general terms your character will struggle with their daily functions and body image. Some other effects that can happen are things like Psychological morbidity, decreased self esteem, increased dependency and significant levels of social isolation. Surprisingly only around 30% of healthy young people who get an amputation get depressions (as in the long term debilitating one I assume). This is about people who knew the amputation was coming, however. Not a forceful mutilation, which the removal of one leg and changing the other in a functional fishtail is to a human.

The exact detailes of these effects vary greatly, giving you leeway to fill it in based on how you and your audience would expect it to go.